# How To Get Conditional HTML Field Values

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get the Full Name value in PHP depending upon the following condition, but it is giving me error of Undefined Index "FullName". Any Help would be appericiated:

```
<?php if(isset($Name)) { ?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $Name; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name(As Per CNIC)" name="FullName" id="FullName" required disabled>
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name(As Per CNIC)" name="FullName" id="FullName" required>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This code cannot give you that error.

Comment: This is not the failing part of your code, can you add the failing code to the snippet? that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: I am trying to get this value in PHP using $FullName = $_POST['FullName']; This value is giving me Undefined Index error FulName

Comment: This may just be a typo - but in a couple of your comments, you refer to `FulName` which is with 1 l, not `FullName`.

Comment: It was a typo Error It is **`FullName`**

Answer (score 1):

Before you do this `$FullName = $_POST['FullName'];` 
check if it is empty

```
if (!empty($_POST['FullName'])) {

  $FullName = $_POST['FullName'];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably will not answer your question but, I can't add it to the comments section since there is some code:

to fix the error/warning just add if a check to your code, like this

```
...
if(!empty($_POST['FullName']) {
   $FullName = $_POST['FullName'];
  ...
}
...
```

Also an advice for readability when mixing PHP with HTML:

```
<?php if(isset($Name)): ?>
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $Name; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name(As Per CNIC)" name="FullName" id="FullName" required disabled>
<?php else: ?>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name(As Per CNIC)" name="FullName" id="FullName" required>
<?php endif; ?>
```